# вопрос о реализации перехода между фрагментами

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

мне нужно реализовать нормальный переход между фрагментами с сохранением старого фрагмента (чтоб не вызывался onCreateView и тд.
тоесть, например при запуске приложения создаются 2 фрагмента и сохраняются, а потом можно переключать между ними.

Я смотрел различные решения в интернете, но там не так.

Как у меня сейчас переход реализован между фрагментами?

Я пишу приложение для загрузки всех игр, разработанных компанией.
Переход между страницами игр существует в верхнем разделе и в странице со всеми играми.
Пользователь выбирает игру и грузится фрагмент.

но есть минус - каждый раз старый фрагмент, так скажем похоже удаляется, а также если скачивание поставить на паузу, то оно и в другой фрагмент заходит (нет разделения так скажем).

Тоесть мне нужно под каждую игру чтоб создавался полноценный фрагмент и сохранялся и чтоб можно было выполнять в них действия, чтоб один не мешал другому. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил.

Я не смог найти решение. Может какую то стороннюю библиотеку нужно использовать? Или я не понимаю чего то элементарного?

Мой код загрузки фрагмента:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Как-то очень туманно всё. Непонятна схема навигации между фрагментами - соответственно неясно можно и нужно ли вообще сохранять их экземпляры. Опишите подробнее.

Comment: @woesss, вот обьясню. Я разрабатываю приложение, подобное Wargaming Game Center (в т.ч максимально похожее по дизайну), можете посмотреть на скриншоты и сразу все поймете.

Список с играми грузится у меня еще в SplashActivity, все остальное (новости и т.д) грузится в фрагменте.
Сама навигация сделана таким образом: сверху установленные/скачиваемые игры. 
Пользователь переключается между ними и если например одна игра установлена и готова к запуску, то другая например может скачиваться. А третья может что то еще.
Вот поэтому мне нужно полноценное разделение с сохранением.

Answer (score 0):

ну это уже вопрос к архитектурным подходам.
лично бы рекомендовал вам смотреть в сторону MVVM подхода с ViewModel'ю.

вам не надо "под каждую игру чтоб создавался полноценный фрагмент".
вам надо "загрузить список игр и сохранять его" и "каждую выранную инфу об игре загрузить и где-то сохранить".

если я правильно понял, то вам надо всего 2 фрагмента:
со списком всех игр и детальная инфа про выбранную игру.

прогружаете список всех игр для 1ого фрагмента в 1ый массив.
2ой массив с деталями об играх. по умолчанию пустой.
выбираете игру, переходите на 2ой фрагмент.
если инфа про эту игру есть во 2ом массиве - отображете.
нет - прогружаете ее, сохраняете, отображаете.

возможно, я не так понял задачу.

Comment: У меня все списки то сохраняются, посмотрите выше, комментарий оставил. Теперь я понял как обьяснить конкретно: 

одна игра может быть установленной, другая может скачиваться, третья может обновляться и так далее.

Comment: почти такой же как wargaming game center

Comment: ну как вариант тогда да, у каждой игры должен быть свой фрагмент. а логику держать во viewModel, которая и будет заниматься скачиванием, обновлением, паузой и прочей логикой. фрагменты - масимально тупые и лишь для UI.

Comment: к сожалению, не имею опыта с работой viewModel, никогда с ним не работал. Я кстати создавал массив с инфой о созданных фрагментах, и вызывал их оттуда. Это улучшило поведение, но не намного.

Comment: наконец, после около сотни перерытых статей о ViewModel, мне немного стало понятно в чем тут дело.

фрагмент не имеет свойство сохранять жизнь и в случае перехода разрушается (onDestroy). Поэтому если я хочу реализовать постоянную возможность скачивания (не прерывая процесс во время перехода) то мне надо это делать где то в другом месте, а данные отправлять в фрагмент.
Но разве viewModel умеет выполнять закачки например? Умеет передавать прогресс закачки и все такое?

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper конечно умеет. но тут кнчн еще вопрос "что вы используете для асинхронщины: RxJava, Coroutine, Thread?". вьюмодель как раз и нужна для того, чтобы не привзяывать к ЖЦ экранов и скачивание не прерывалось, если пользователь поменяет ориентацию экрана.

Comment: ориентация мне не важна, у меня всегда горизонтал :)

Я использую для загрузки файлов библиотеку FileDownloader (com.liulishuo.filedownloader).
Для распаковки - AsyncTask.

Для операций с сетью использую Thread.

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper я бы советовал попробовать использовать ViewModel (в частности SharedViewMOdel) и вынести в нее абсолютно всю логику и переменные. почитай еще про LiveData и будет вам счастье. фрагменты и будут уничтожаться при навигации, но сама логика работы и загрузки и данные будут сохранены в пределах вашего ЖЦ активити.

Comment: сегодня решил попробовать AndroidViewModel с MutableLiveData. Пока попробовал подключить только одну переменную - тип установки.
Вроде переменная работает, но есть одно но. При каждом переходе он очищается (onCleared).
Я так понял, инициализировать VM надо в активити, а не в фрагменте?
но мне нужно чтоб под каждый фрагмент была отдельная VM

Comment: AndroidViewModel отличается от просто ViewModel лишь тем, чем у первой будет доступ к контектсту. так же ВьюМодели делиться на 2 типа ViewModel и SharedViewModel. обычная ВьюМодель привязана к ЖЦ хозяина (активити или фрагмента). когда вы уничтожаете хоязина (не считая поворот экрана) уничтожается и ВМ. а вот SharedViewModel (она доступна фрагментам) привязываетяс к ЖЦ активити фрагмента. т.е. пока жива активити, вы можете хоть 100500 раз уничтожать фрагмент - данные никуда не денуться. p.s. можете связаться со мной телеграмм @punk_bass

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь. Сейчас вам напишу